# When does a dir in /proc/ modified date changes?

Tags: c, linux, unix, proc

I'm attempting to get the date of a creation of a process, but since POSIX only supports Accessed, Modified, and Changed dates i can't seem to "stat" any file.
so maybe i can use the "modified" date of the process directory? like "/proc/2206" and take the modified date from the output struct?

thats why i want to know when does the folder's "modified" date changes?
note: I'm Programming and not using any tools like "ps"

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [stat(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat)  system call on `/proc/2206/stat` file -for process of pid `2206`-  (or on `/proc/self/stat` from inside the process). Read more about the Linux [proc(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) pseudo-file system.

It seems that all the access, modify, change times of that `/proc/*/stat` file are the start time of the considered process.

Remember that files under `/proc/` are pseudo-files provided by the linux kernel, which are read quickly and do not involve any disk activity.

Comment: thank you, i got it now, but i dont think this applies to solaris, does it?

Comment: you tagged your question with *Linux* ..... Indeed, Posix don't specify much how to query process status programmatically. So each system has its own way...